# Coordinate generation for memory card game

Tags: java, android, coordinates, andengine

How can I generate (x, y) coordinates for a memory card game? Let's say I can set the number of cards, rows and columns. How would my for loop look like?

My general idea is as follows:

```
final int ROWS = 4;
final int COLUMNS = 5;

for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j<COLUMNS; j++){
        //calculate X coordinate
        int index = some_calculation
        MemoryCard memoryCard = new MemoryCard(x, y, index);
    }
    //calculate y coordinate
}
```

However, I'm having an issue creating my objects here. The above loop will go 4 times for i and 5 times for j. So, in total I have 20 objects there. But how do I get to my object's index? 
Let's say I have an array list of my objects:

```
private ArrayList<MemoryCard> objects = new ArrayList<MemoryCard>();
//parameters for MemoryCard object are (float x, float y, Texture frontImage)
```

Is there a way to make this dynamic? To make the program generate proper positions if I set number of ROWS to 3 and COLUMS to 6? Or any other even pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can translate easy...

```
public int getIndexOf(int x, int y){
    return x + y * ROWS;
}
```

and revert as well...

```
public int getXFromIndex(int index){
    return index%ROWS;
}

public int getYFromIndex(int index){
    return index/ROWS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I opted for this solution and it seems to work!

Comment: i'm glad i could help - i use such conversions all day long, used on big tile maps wich are stored into a sparse-array...

Answer (score 2):

Martin Frank already provided the correct answer to your question, but I'd like to present an alternative solution. Instead of serializing your rows and columns into a 1D array list, why not use a 2D array?

```
MemoryCard[][] cards = new MemoryCard[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

Then you can access your card on row x and column y just like this:

```
MemoryCard card = cards[x][y];
```

Comment: I'll try it like that. I didn't even know about 2D arrays till now o.O

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it would be better to use a 2D array which will be easier to maintain and visualize positions, something like

```
Objects[][] memoryCards;
```

Then to fill it you just use your loop.